# Numlock and CAPSLOCK turned always ON in VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hello i have a form written in VBA Access , when i type or select some values from comboboz or text some values, my NUMLOCK And CAPSLOCK key are turning OFF, how to make that they ALWAYS will be ON , i can't figure how?

Comment: Are you using SendKeys at all?

Comment: what sendkeys can i use?

Comment: Never mind, was thinking of http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this](http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0046.htm) has code that will check and set **capslock**, **numlock** and **scrolllock**.

It uses the windows APIs

```
  Private Declare Function GetKeyboardState Lib "user32" _
     (pbKeyState As Byte) As Long
  Private Declare Function SetKeyboardState Lib "user32" _
     (lppbKeyState As Byte) As Long
```

to check and set the keyboard state - with this API, other fun things are available, such as playing with the windows key.